# Caffeine and system settings and upper right hand corner

Tags: password, sudo

I was able to go to the terminal and type in the command for caffeine, but I don't find caffeine anywhere in the system settings and it doesn't show up anywhere on the upper right hand corner of the screen and I did reboot. Does this mean it does now work? Where and how would I find caffeine so I can click on it to start it?

Comment: try    caffeine-indicator command in terminal, set it to start on boot... if you need further explanation:http://m.webupd8.org/2015/01/caffeine-app-gets-its-indicator-back.html?m=1   
http://www.howtogeek.com/189995/how-to-manage-startup-applications-in-ubuntu-14.04/

Comment: I tried typing caffeine-indicator into the terminal, but it says there is no such command.

Comment: then follow links I have provided...

Comment: I followed the links you provided, but it doesn't say anywhere about the caffeine-indicator. And as I just got onto my computer, the screensaver dimmed again after I typed everything into the terminal! Why is this not working? Do I need to do something else in the terminal after I put the command in and it says it's O.K.